# MS "Word": finding all words highlighted with one specific color

Tags: microsoft-word, finder

How is it possible (or is it possible at all) in MS "Word" to find with the finder all the symbols that are highlighted with one specific color?

For example, here I have this text:

[image]

If I need to find all occurrences of the word "one" in it I can easily do that by entering "one" in the finder:

[image]

But what if I have some words already highlighted in the text, say, in turquoise?:

[image]

How is it possible then to find all those turquoise words in text?

Answer (score 1):

Using build-in Find and Replace feature can't help us find text using a specific highlighting color.

[image]

The only way around this is to use a macro to do the finding. VBA allows you to detect the color used to highlight text, which is why this approach will work. The following macro uses Find and Replace to do the finding, but then it checks to see what the HighlightColorIndex property is for what was found. If it is equal to wdYellow (an enumeration for the color yellow), then the text is selected and the macro is exited.

```
Sub FindNextYellow()
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Highlight = True
    Do
        .Execute
    Loop Until Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow _
      Or Not .Found
    Selection.Range.Select
End With 
End Sub
```

You can search for different colors simply by changing the wdYellow enumeration to the enumeration for whatever color you want.

Reference:[Finding Text Using a Specific Highlighting Color](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013552_Finding_Text_Using_a_Specific_Highlighting_Color.html) by Allen Wyatt

Comment: Just a remark: if two contiguous pieces of text have different coloured highlights applied, Find will find the entire text and HighlightColorIndex will be 999999. So in theory it might be necessary to iterate through the found .Range looking for characters with the requested color.

Comment: this takes a long time on LONG documents (i.e. 1000 pages) and appears to scroll the text while it searches, reducing performance significantly. Is there a way to have it search without scrolling, and only scroll when a result is found?

Answer (score 0):

You can't search for a specific color, but Word does offer a find `Highlight` option. You click the drop arrow next to the magnifying glass and choose `Advanced Find ...`. Click the `Format` button and click `Highlight`. You can then click the `Find Next` button to move through the results.
[image: Find Hightlight image]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.